# Dynamically property .Not.Insert().Not.Update() Mapping Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

im using the Fluent NHibernate together with the automapping functionality!

I'm currently using the follwing mapping statement to prevent autogenerated column values to be updated / insert

```
.Override<Entity>(map => map.Map(d => d.STATUS).Not.Insert().Not.Update())
```

It works fine so far, but now im looking for a way to get this solved more dynamically.

What i would like to do is:

I want to declare a custom attribute called [ReadOnlyDbField] and then declare all properties of the entity with this custom attribute to say: Just read this value and do not update / insert it.

Then i want to tell the mapping configuration:

```
Map all properties with the custom attribute [ReadOnlyDbField] to Not.Insert().Not.Update()
```

Is there a way to get this?

Thanks

**Daniel**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Generated method

```
Map(x => x.Status).Generated.Never(); // or Insert() or Always()
```

For auto application look at [conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions), some examples [here](http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-conventions-examples/).

Comment: Hello Karel. Thanks for the idea - but i don't know who to implement my needs with the generated method. Maybe i have a blockhead? :)

Answer (score 0):

You must create an attribute class

```
public class NoInsertUpdateAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

and another class for its convention:

```
public class NoInsertUpdateConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<NoInsertUpdateAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(NoInsertUpdateAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Not.Insert();
        instance.Not.Update();
    }
}
```

and add container assembly of NoInsertUpdateConvention class to automap:

```
var fluentConfiguration = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Mappings(
                m => {
                    var autoMap = AutoMap
                        .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<NoInsertUpdateConvention>()
                }
            );
```

finally add attribute to property you do not want to be inserted or updated:

```
    [NoInsertUpdate]
    public virtual int? AccountID { get; set; }
```